# Gradle sync failed: Illegal char <:> at index 52

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

**While Building the Android project I am facing this issue, Also I have cross checked my System environment variables but not able to identified the actual issue:**

Caused by: java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Illegal char <:> at index 52: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin;\build-tools\28.0.3

Please help me out for it.

Comment: The last path entry ( \build-tools\28.0.3 )  does not look to me as a valid Windows path.

Comment: @AudriusMeskauskas, you can write it as an answer.

Comment: Additionally, does your `username` consist only of English symbols and digits without spaces?

Comment: @CoolMind I just replaced my system username with username here.

Comment: @AudriusMeskauskas I am not able to find this "The last path entry ( \build-tools\28.0.3 ) " path anywhere can u pls guide me

Comment: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\bin;\build-tools\28.0.3`. Note `;` between `\bin` and `\build-tools`.

Comment: @CoolMind but i am not able to find this path anywhere -  \build-tools\28.0.3 ) can you tell me where i need to check?

Comment: @CoolMind Its working fine after reset all the system environment variables

Comment: @vijaychhalotre, good! I forgot to say that they were in environment variables. Thought you knew that.